# Microsoft Access 2010 lag in continuous form header subforms

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I am a research student working on an access database where I have created a continuous form that is to be used in a sort of scrolling electronic health record format. The header includes information about the patient and the continuous form aspect is a series of patient visits. In the header, I have a few subforms, which populate based on linking on the patient_ID number which is posted in the header (generated by vba macro such that previously reviewed patients aren't revisited). These subforms seem to significantly lag such that they the results from the previous patient stick around going into the next one. The subforms contain user-selected pertinent data. Each form has its own table. They are linked primarily based on patient_ID.

I have tried:

1. macro on the header detail: on click, refresh. - seems to work, but not very elegant/intuitive
2. macro on the main form - same as above but on load, click, got focus, lost focus, open, activate -- none of them seem to do anything.
3. forced requery via vba (see below) on opening/etc of the form. Neither way has worked. Tried to run these on opening the header form.

   `Public Function RequeryMain()
       Dim frmMain As Form
       Set frm = Forms("FRM_continuous_reports_patient")
       frm.Requery
   End Function`

   `Public Function RequeryHeader()
       Dim frmHeader As SubForm
       Set frmHeader = Forms("FRM_continuous_reports_patient").FRM_continuous_header_working
       frmHeader.Requery
   End Function`

In the end, it is frustrating for users to have to click to clear the form for new entries. It works otherwise.

The end goal is for the form to open and have all the subforms load based on the newest patient_ID. This would likely have to involve a staggered load: (1) VBA script selects the next patient based on certain characteristics and passes the patient_ID to the main form; (2) load main continuous form based on patient_ID submitted to it; (3) load the header subforms and any pertinent data within (although should be blank for the first time these are seen); (4) on completion, back to (1).

From what I understand, this is already how it is working, however the subforms are loading too quickly? How can I fix this?

Hopefully someone can help explain how to remedy this/correct any misunderstandings I have about the mechanics of forms.

Comment: SInce subforms *normally* open before main forms, you need to delay the subform. Take a look at: https://accessexperts.com/blog/2013/12/18/prevent-subforms-in-access-from-loading-before-main-forms/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards that. So I changed the subforms to call from the original patient_ID. (I tag the patient as "in use" before opening the form). I would expect that by removing the dependence on the main form it would have fixed this issue, however it doesn't seem to have changed anything?

Comment: Did you see the comment in that link that said "Ben will talk about disabling the loading of subforms on startup in our next post." where 'next post' is another link?

Comment: No, I had missed that! quickly jumped to the next bit. I am a little confused by the code in it. (1) Do I place this is the main form or the header? Specifically where does this code go for the form? (2) This involves removing the Source Object for each subform and then subsequently reassigning it after the main form has loaded? (3) How do Cases work? I have not used them before. I largely use Python. VBA has only been for this project. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: 1) Probably in form Open or Load or Current event. 2) Yes. 3) Google. Build code and test. If you have issues, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will sound odd, but subforms actually load before parent form. Lag in subform display is not something I have encountered. Code should not be needed and likely will not correct. Must be something about the form/subform design, maybe their RecordSource. Would have to examine db to determine.

It is not necessary to create form objects in VBA just to requery. Is code behind the main form? `Me.Requery` will be enough for the main form. I always give subform container a name different from the object it holds, like ctrPatient. Then just `Me.ctrPatient.Requery`.

Why not put subforms in Detail section?

Comment: You are right. I actually had put them in the Detail section not the proper header. Just tried placing Me.Requery in Private Sub Form_Load() of the header form, however it doesn't seem to work either. I think I might have misunderstood something? Thanks

Comment: So why subforms in main form Header and not Detail? I have never had this issue and therefore never tried any code like this. No, Requery code in subform Load won't work mainly because the main form is not yet loaded. Would have to be code in the main form event that references the subform. That's what my answer describes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, and provide a condensed version of the logic referenced at:  https://accessexperts.com/blog/2014/01/07/delay-loading-subforms-in-access/

is to:

1. In design view, set your subform SourceObject to "" (and save your form)
2. When you are ready to show the subform, just execute: Me..SourceObject = ""
3. When you are ready to navigate to the NEXT patient, clear the subform link: Me..SourceObject = ""

Now that should solve the issue of out of sync data between the main and sub.

You don't need to use the CASE statements, but they operate as if you had a bunch of "If" / "ElseIf" all nestled together -- except the CASE makes it easier to follow. It basically gets a value from a variable (i.e. Select Case MyVariable); then checks to see if it equals what you want (Case 1, Case 2, etc.), and if so, does whatever you code.